# Javascript patterns resources

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture

I know that this kind of issue is most discussed. But I would like to hear some opinions from you.

Where should I start looking for some valuable resources on Design Patterns for Javascript? What pattern should I follow for a medium-large type application?

I'd like to learn something that could use jQuery library.

What is your opinion about this approach to Model View Controller design for Js? ->
[JavascriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/)

My priorities are: performance, well separated application-tiers and scalability.

Regards

Comment: I would urge you to consider exactly what you want to build first, then consider how to do it, and then check to see if you can find some design patterns to suit your needs. That way, you will not end up being "trapped" by any particular pattern.

Comment: i am following this blog : http://www.as3dp.com/category/javascript/ The person used to write a lot of ActionScript design pattern but slowly add more topic about design pattern using Javacript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a very good book on how to write good JavaScript Code.
Its title is "JavaScript Patterns by Stoyan Stefanov [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do)

Take a look at such frameworks as knockoutJS or backboneJS which allow you to implement the MVC or the MVVM pattern very easily --> separation of concerns. Besides I would definitely structure my logic in modules. Take a look at the CommonJS module specification and the requiereJS  as an example of the implementation of this specification. It allows you to conditionally load your JavaScript on demand with all dependencies -->performance and structuring.

You could also write your logic in the form of jQuery plugins.